# C# and ASP.NET MVC 5 / Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view that displays a data from an external Web API in a gridview. When a record is selected from the grid, the code navigates to a details page/view.

The details view displays additional demographic data. From the details page I need to submit the details form and grab a few data elements that will be passed to my controller so I can POST a transaction to the external Web API.

I am currently getting 'null' values in the controller. The error is:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id'

Do I need to pass a parameter to the controller? Help appreciated.

Model.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CPA.Models
{
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class AlertMessage
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Severity { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemLine
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int BilledAmount { get; set; }
        public int PaidAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public class CitationDetail
    {
        public string CitationNumber { get; set; }
        public string DefendantName { get; set; }
        public string DateofBirth { get; set; }
        public string VehicleTagNumber { get; set; }
        public string CaseType { get; set; }
        public string CaseStatus { get; set; }
        public string AppearanceDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsPayable { get; set; }
        public int FineSuspended { get; set; }
        public int FineServed { get; set; }

        public List<AlertMessage> AlertMessages { get; set; }
        public List<ItemLine> ItemLines { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<CitationDetail> CitationDetails { get; set; }
        public int CitationCount { get; set; }
        public bool SuccessfulSearch { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<h2>Details</h2>

<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index3", "Citation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
                <input type="text" id="txtcitationnber" value=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CitationNumber) />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DefendantName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DefendantName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateofBirth)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateofBirth)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VehicleTagNumber)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.VehicleTagNumber)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaseType)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CaseType)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CaseStatus)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CaseStatus)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppearanceDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AppearanceDate)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsPayable)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsPayable)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FineSuspended)

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FineSuspended)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FineServed)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FineServed)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor=#c0c0c0>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AlertMessages)
            </td>
        </tr>
        @if (@Model.AlertMessages != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.AlertMessages.Count; i += 1)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AlertMessages);
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="#ffc426">
            <td>Description </td>
            <td> BilledAmount</td>
            <td> PaidAmount</td>
        </tr>
        @if (@Model.ItemLines != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < Model.ItemLines.Count; i += 1)
            {

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemLines[i].Description) </td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemLines[i].BilledAmount)</td>
                    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ItemLines[i].PaidAmount);</td>
                </tr>

            }
        }

        <tr>
            <td>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr bgcolor="#c0c0c0">
            <td>Charge Code </td>
            <td> Payment Amount</td>
            <td>  </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="chargecodes">
                    <option value="500002">BF</option>
                    <option value="5000BT">BT</option>
                    <option value="500007">BV</option>
                    <option value="5000RE">RE</option>
                    <option value="500001">TC</option>
                    <option value="500004">CB</option>
                    <option value="500008">MI</option>
                    <option value="500011">OT</option>s
                    <option value="500012">PB</option>
                    <option value="500010">PK</option>
                    <option value="500009">PP</option>
                    <option value="500005">SB</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="paymentamount" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
}
</body>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index3(CitationDetail citation)
// public ActionResult Index(FormCollection citation)
{
    try
    {
        string citationnbr = citation.CitationNumber;

        ViewData["CitationNumber"] = citationnbr;

        var client2 = new RestClient("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8109/api/xxxxx/Citation/PostTransaction");
        client2.Timeout = -1;

        var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Creating Json object
        // JObject jObjectbody = new JObject();
        // jObjectbody.Add("ValidatePayment", "Validate");
        // jObjectbody.Add("ValidatePayment", "Payment");
        // jObjectbody.Add("TransactionType", chargenbr);
        // jObjectbody.Add("CitationNumber", citation.CitationNumber);
        // jObjectbody.Add("TransactionAmount", pmt);
        // jObjectbody.Add("MachineNumber", "24");
        // jObjectbody.Add("CashierNumber", "25");
        // jObjectbody.Add("CheckNumber", "0");
        // jObjectbody.Add("CloseOut", "Y");
        // jObjectbody.Add("ReceiptNumber", "0");
        // jObjectbody.Add("RevenueType", chargecode);
        // jObjectbody.Add("TransactionDate", DateTime.Now);

        // request2.AddParameter("application/json", jObjectbody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        // IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue comes from your view.

First of all, you have to precise to the view which model you want to use. So at the top of your view you can write :

```
@model CPA.Models.CitationDetail
```

In your view, you're just showing "CitationDetail" attributes names, so when you submit your form, you don't send any data because you don't have any input.

To send data you need to use the following html helper :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.YourAttribute)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourAttribute)
```

This html helper will generate the following html code:

```html
<label for="YourAttribute">YourAttribute</label>
<input id="YourAttribute" name="YourAttribute" value="">
```

You just need to add to your form an input for each attribute of your class.

For example in your view, the correct form input for your attribute 'CitationNumber' would be :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CitationNumber)
```